# JSF composite-library-name and subfolders

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, taglib, composite-component, subdirectory

I using primefaces 2.2. And have next `facelet-taglib` defenition:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0">
<namespace>http://someUrl/portal_composite</namespace>
<composite-library-name>composite</composite-library-name>
```

This defenition includes only tags placed under `/composite` and ignores all subfolders tags. How can I include tags form `/composite/somefolder` to the same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

`composite-library-name` points to a library. A library in JSF is logically flat and contains resources that have specific structure (see [JavaServer™ Faces Specification Version 2.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/index.html)):

```
[localePrefix/][libraryName/][libraryVersion/]resourceName[/resourceVersion]
```

As you see there can be multiple versions of library inside subdirectories and similarly multiple versions of resources but these have special meaning.